# Update Unity AI Text every x minutes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I have a day of the year, a year and an hour of the day concatanated to form a UI text value in the top left of the page. 
I am forming the above with an index from a dayOfYear array, followed by a number for the year, followed by an index of a hourInDay array.

For example, this creates the following: '1st Janauary 2371 00:00'

I want to move the hour along by 1 every 5 minutes in real world time, then when it gets to 23:00, reset the hour array and increment the day array to show 2nd January and so on.

Displaying the above works fine, but when I try to run a function to incrementthe the hour every five minutes, nothing happens but there are no errors in the console. I have tried a co-routine, I have tried with invokerepeating on a function which increments the current array index for the hour and I have also tried on top of this, setting a reference to the UI text again in Update(); I also have a reference to UnityEngine.UI.

My code below. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Like I say, when I start the game the correct date is shown based on the Array indexes concatenated, but nothing progresses after 5 seconds.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class PassageOfTime : MonoBehaviour
{
public float yearNo;
public string dayNo;
public int currentDay;
public string hourNo;
public int currentHour;
public string gameDateTime;


public Text DateTimeText;


string[] hourInDay = new string[]
{
"00:00",
"01:00",
"02:00",
"03:00",
"04:00",
"05:00",
"06:00",
"07:00",
"08:00",
"09:00",
"10:00",
"11:00",
"12:00",
"13:00",
"14:00",
"15:00",
"16:00",
"17:00",
"18:00",
"19:00",
"19:00",
"20:00",
"21:00",
"22:00",
"23:00"
};

string[] dayInYear = new string[]
{
  "January 1st",
  "January 2nd",
  "January 3rd",
  "January 4th",
  "January 5th",
  "January 6th",
  "January 7th",
  "January 8th",
  "January 9th",
  "January 10th",
  "January 11th",
  "January 12th",
  "January 13th",
  "January 14th",
  "January 15th",
  "January 16th",
  "January 17th",
  "January 18th",
  "January 19th",
  "January 20th",
  "January 21st",
  "January 22nd",
  "January 23rd",
  "January 24th",
  "January 25th",
  "January 26th",
  "January 27th",
  "January 28th",
  "January 29th",
  "January 30th",
  "January 31st",
  "February 1st",
  "Feburary 2nd"
};

void incrementYear()
{
    yearNo += 1;
}

void incrementDay()
{
    currentDay += 1;
    currentHour = 0;
}

void incrementHour()
{
    currentHour += 1;

}

void ProgressTime()
{
    incrementHour();
    DateTimeText = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
    DateTimeText.text = gameDateTime;

}


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    DateTimeText = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
    currentDay = 0;
    currentHour = 0;
    dayNo = dayInYear[currentDay];
    hourNo = hourInDay[currentHour];
    yearNo = 2371;

    gameDateTime = dayNo + "  " + yearNo + "  " + hourNo;

    DateTimeText.text= gameDateTime.ToString();
    InvokeRepeating("ProgressTime", 5.0f, 5.0f);




}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

   DateTimeText.text = gameDateTime.ToString();
}
```

}

Comment: But you are modifying `gameDateTime` once in the `Start` function. You are never changing it again. Do you want it to automatically update it self? Maybe you should put `gameDateTime = dayNo + "  " + yearNo + "  " + hourNo;` in one of those functions that is updated once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your gameDatetime after you make some increment:

```
void ProgressTime()
{
    incrementHour();
    gameDateTime = dayNo + "  " + yearNo + "  " + hourNo;
    DateTimeText = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
    DateTimeText.text = gameDateTime;


}
```

Comment: Will give this a go and let you know how I get on :)

Comment: Another attractive way to do the time cycle is with a Tick Event and you subscribe to this event to raise your ProgressTime

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much!